# How can I do setf on a struct's accessors when using intern

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

I'd like to `setf` different fields of a struct depending on a certain variable.  I decided to use the following approach:

Generate a string with the field's accessor name:

```
(setq my-string (format nil "STRUCT-ESTADISTICAS-NUM-~S" x))
```

and then use intern with funcall:

```
(funcall (intern my-string) *estadisticas*)
```

This call returns the correct value of the struct's field, but if I try `setf` to modify this value it complains saying:

```
(setf (funcall(intern my-string) *estadisticas*) 0)
Error: `(SETF FUNCALL)' is not fbound
```

I can understand why it doesn't work, but I can't find a way to modify the struct's fields.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Which is it, Emacs Lisp or Common Lisp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to call a writer function of the struct via its name, and the name of the writer is the list `(setf accessor-name)`; so

```
(funcall (fdefinition (list 'setf (intern my-string))) 0 estadisticas)
```

#### Edit:

Not seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to fathom what went wrong.  On SBCL this works for me:

```
(defstruct point x y)
(let ((point (make-point :x 1 :y 2)))
  (funcall (fdefinition (list 'setf (intern "POINT-X"))) 10 point)
  point)
```

The above evaluates to

```
#S(POINT :X 10 :Y 2),
```

as expected.

Comment: Using:   
(funcall(fdefinition (list 'setf (intern "STRUCT-ESTADISTICAS-NUM-1"))) 0 *estadisticas*)

I still get:   
Error: `(SETF STRUCT-ESTADISTICAS-NUM-1)' is not fbound

Comment: don't use INTERN. Use FIND-SYMBOL, maybe check if the symbol is found and also make sure that the accessor is looked up in the correct package.

Comment: That's non-standard, I'd say. DEFSTRUCT is not required to define WRITER functions.

Answer (score 5):

**Motivation:**

Structures are a relatively low-level facility. 'Speed' was an important design goal. Indirection via writer functions is not supported by the standard (as I read it). Today, use CLOS as the default, unless one needs better efficiency of structures (faster read and writes of slots with structures are sometimes possible).

**First - style:**

Don't use INTERN, use FIND-SYMBOL. Also specify the package, otherwise FIND-SYMBOL will use the runtime value of *package* as the package

**Second - DEFSTRUCT**

If I read the ANSI CL standard correctly, it is not that DEFSTRUCT creates writer functions for slots like DEFCLASS does.

```
CL-USER 24 > (defstruct foo bar baz)
FOO

CL-USER 25 > #'(setf foo-bar)

Error: Undefined function (SETF FOO-BAR) in form (FUNCTION (SETF FOO-BAR)).
```

So, constructing such a name (SETF FOO-BAR) and trying to find a function for that will fail, since there is no such function defined by the DEFSTRUCT.

That in user code  (setf (foo-bar some-struct) 42)  works, is based on defined SETF expansions provided by DEFSTRUCT, but not on defined SETF accessor functions.

Some Common Lisp implementations may provide writer functions as a non-standard extension to ANSI CL.

**Possible solutions**:

a) use CLOS classes, DEFCLASS does what you want

b) write the writer functions yourself

```
(defun (setf foo-bar) (new-value struct)
   (setf (foo-bar struct) new-value))
```

Now:

```
(funcall (fdefinition '(setf foo-bar)) 300 *foo*)
```

Above then works.

c) (SETF SLOT-VALUE) - another non-standard feature of some implementations.

In some implementations of Common Lisp this works not only for CLOS classes, but also for structures:

```
(setf (slot-value some-struct 'bar) 42)
```

I'm not sure if Allegro CL does support that, but that would be easy to find out.

Comment: In possible solution b), it may yield an infinitely recursive function, if the Lisp implementation actually generates setf functions for structure slot accessors.